# Angular Service workers ,push notification and subscribed users

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker

I have a big internal angular project. we had some requirements to send users notifications about some processes within work.  I updated the project to angular 8 in the front end and we are using Nodejs and Express as back end. For the main time, everything is going well. But am having a small challenge that is am not able to know if the client is subscribed or not. I know that he is not subscribed I'll show a button for unsubscribing. all subscriptions are saved in DB but some clients have got more than one subscription for different browsers. so is there a way to know if the user is subscribed or not from the used browser or not. any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need a device uid for this to differentiate which user has subscribed from which devices. Keep device uid concated with logged in user id in the database where you have all the subscription details.

Comment: @sibabratswain am doing so. if there is a way to get the subscription endpoint which variable from each device I can compare it. but since the user is not going to subscribe again from the same device it's hard to get the endpoint.

Comment: Do you want the user should get notifications in all the devices he logs in? Or it will be updated to latest login and gets the notification once with the latest device/browser which logged in?

Comment: @sibabratswain yes, he'll be notified on any device and any browser within the same device. if we can know that he is subscribed from the browser that he is using that will increase or functionality

Answer (score 0):

You will need a unique id that you can refer to for every user and can track the subscription and trigger a notification.

I will suggest you to concat a few things and make it unique from browser to browser and device to device.

**Use this plugin to get unique device id**

[device-uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/device-uuid)

**Use this and find the browser name**

```
getBrowserName() {

// @ts-ignore
let isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
if (isOpera) return 'isOpera';
// Firefox 1.0+
// @ts-ignore
let isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
if (isFirefox) return 'isFirefox';

 // Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
// @ts-ignore
let isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) {
  return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]";
  // @ts-ignore
})(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && safari.pushNotification));

if (isSafari) return 'isSafari';

// Internet Explorer 6-11
// @ts-ignore
let isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
if (isIE) return isIE;

 // Edge 20+
// @ts-ignore
let isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
if (isEdge) return 'isEdge';

// Chrome 1 - 71
// @ts-ignore
let isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);
if (isChrome) return 'isChrome';

// Blink engine detection
// @ts-ignore
let isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;
if (isBlink) return 'isBlink';

}
```

Now CONCAT the browser name with UUID and login user id. Track the subscription with the unique id and send notifications to all the browser and device the user logged in.

***You need to consider the browser as uuid will be same for a device in all browsers.***

> const uniqueId = uuid + getBrowserName() + logedInUserId;

I guess this should help you out.